# Index of string and first letter call

Tags: c#

If i write `'a'` in the run time , the program should display all the name starting  with `'a'` stored in a text file .

Whenever i write any letter, the names starting with that letter should be displayed.

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText("Data.txt");
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("Data.txt")) ;
```

Comment: Please better explain what is your question..

Comment: Show what you've tried. I've tried to edit your question so its clearer what you're asking, but you still need to show some effort on your own part

Comment: i was saying that i have stored so many names in text file now  i want display all the name starting with 'a' or any other alphabet , how can i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I assume you mean is that you want to select only the lines from your fine (that each line represents a name) that begin with a given input (for example `a`)

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();

var result = File.ReadLines("data.txt").Where(line => line.StartsWith(input)).ToList();
```

to display all the names in one blow you can use:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", result));
```

---

In the case each line in your file contains more than one name then you can split it like this: (For this example the way to separate between names is `,`):

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();

var result = File.ReadLines("data.xml")
                 .SelectMany(line => line.Split(','))
                 .Select(name => name.Trim())
                 .Where(line => line.StartsWith(input)).ToList();
```

Comment: great answer, I also had it in mind; since the op seem to want to display it I would add : `Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", result));`

Comment: @MongZhu - Suggest an edit and I'll accept it :) You deserve it :P

Comment: @Sayse - true but from how he described it it seems so. Otherwise he should also specify a separator so I can split by..

Comment: @Sayse - The file I had on my machine testing it was with an .xml extension but it has no influence what so ever on the result - It reads it just as a simple text file

Comment: @Sayse - Agree with your point of question being really unclear. About the xml - what I meant is that the extension was .xml but it had plain text with no xml tags